# Calculate total cost for all objects in a list Dictionary

Tags: c#, list

I'm a programming student in C# and I have been asked to program an application but I cant figure out how to take all the objects and calculate the total price.

Any help would be good if you can reference me to an another page or answer

Thanks it the `public decimal TotalCost()`

```
namespace GCUShows
{
    public class Booking
    {
        private const int LIMIT = 6;

        // TODO: This class should include the following:
        // instance variable show which is a reference to a Show object

        public Show show;
        private int bookingID;
        public List<ITicket> tickets;

        public int BookingID
        {
            get { return bookingID; }
            set { bookingID = value; }
        }

        public Booking(Show show)
        {
            this.BookingID = BookingIDSequence.Instance.NextID;
            this.show = show;
            show.AddBooking(this);
            this.tickets = new List<ITicket>();
        }

        public void AddTickets(int number, TicketType type, decimal fee)
        {
            // TODO:this method should instantiate the specified number of tickets of the
            // specified type and add these to the list of tickets in this booking
            if (type == TicketType.Adult)
            {
                for(int i =0; i < number; i++)
                {
                    tickets.Add(new AdultTicket(show.Title, fee));
                }
            }
                else if (type == TicketType.Child)
                {
                    for(int i=0; i< number; i++)
                    {
                        tickets.Add(new ChildTicket(show.Title));
                     }
                }
            else if (type == TicketType.Family)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
                {
                    tickets.Add(new FamilyTicket(show.Title, fee));
                }
             }
        }

        public string PrintTickets()
        {
            string ticketInfo = "Booking " + bookingID.ToString() + "\n";
            foreach (ITicket ticket in tickets)
            {
                ticketInfo += ticket.Print();
            }
            return ticketInfo;
        }

        public decimal TotalCost()
        {
            // TODO: this method should return the total cost of the tickets in this booking
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}: Total Cost={1:c}", bookingID, TotalCost());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add the ITicket definition to your example.

Comment: Looks fun, good luck with it! Keep up updated on your progress.

Comment: What keeps you from summing up all tickets' costs when you already did so with the tickets texts in PrintTickets?

Comment: @nvoigt You don't know if PrintTickets was just called or called at all.

Comment: In PrintTickets you should us Stringbuilder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is a `Cost` property in `ITicket`, you can use LINQ (add `using System.Linq` at the top of your file):

```
tickets.Select(x => x.Cost).Sum();
```

Or even simply:

```
tickets.Sum(x => x.Cost);
```

Comment: why not `tickets.Sum(t => t.Cost)`?

Comment: @decPL Only because I didn't remember that this overload existed!

Answer (score 0):

Well you need a way to find all of the tickets you have and go through them one-by-one to find a running total.

If you look at the variables you have declared, (and are using when you call AddTickets), what do you think will be suitable?

> Your `public List<ITicket> tickets;` as it holds a list of all of our tickets

We then need to use an Iterator (something that will look at each object in turn) to add up all our totals. Have we done this anywhere else in our code?

> Look in our Print method - it goes through our collection iteratively using a foreach loop
>  
>  `foreach (ITicket ticket in tickets)`
>  `{`
>  `ticketInfo += ticket.Print();`
>  `}`

You can then just combine this with the cost property on your ITicket to get a running total, eg

> `Decimal totalCost;`
>  `foreach (ITicket ticket in tickets)`
>  `{`
>  `totalCost += ticket.Fee;`
>  `}`
>  `return totalCost;`

Answer (score 0):

To the point:

You're already iterating over your tickets in your print method. Use something similar to add all the fees up and return the result<sup>[1](https://gist.github.com/29f7ac324327315eb8e2.git)</sup>.

> `decimal totalPrice = 0.0m;`
>  `foreach (ITicket ticket in tickets)`
>  `{`
>      `totalPrice += ticket.Fee;`
>  `}`
>  `return totalPrice;`

Some constructive criticism:

- The `BookingIDSequence` singelton really isn't necessary unless you're using it outside of the `Booking` class. If you're only keeping a tally of Booking IDs, think about making that a static property of your `Booking` class and assigning/incrementing it in your `Booking` constructor.

  - If you do decide to keep it, and though this is probably semantic, it's a good idea to use a method with a verb to make it clear what its purpose is (e.g. `.GetNextId()` over `.NextId`) Then anyone using that class understands what's going on.
- Ticket fees should be migrated to the Ticket classes themselves. When you go to add a child ticket, the `fee` parameter becomes useless (but still required). Moreover, tickets and fees are 1:1 and makes sense to keep them compartmentalized.

  - You could even extend `ITicket` with business logic like `AddDiscount(Decimal percent)` etc.
- Instead of using if statements in `AddTickets` you should look at a switch statement. It's an either/or kind of decision, but for enumerations they're generally cleaner looking.
- Along the same lines as `NextId`, `TotalCost` would be more concise renamed to `GetTotalCost()`.

Extra credit:

- Look at using `StringBuilder` in your print method.
- Look up the factory pattern for creating your `ITicket` types.